# How to perform deep partition table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

For example, I have three tables `table_1`, `table_2` and `table_3` with following structure.

[image]

Now I know how to perform partition `BY RANGE` on `table_1` which will provide me with following partitions

[image]

However, I want to perform deep partition so I will achieve following partitions

[image]

I feel like deeply segregating data by date will improve performance. Most heave data query is done on `table_3` so it would be nice to partition it by date which is determined by relationship from `table_1`. Is this possible?

Comment: It's called sub-partitioning and yes it's supported. There are some examples [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXAMPLES)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is also called `multi-level` partitioning right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. It seems to be partitioning the existing partition. If it is for my case, it will be portioning table_1 and partition table_1's partitions further which is not what I am looking for. I guess I am trying to create `matching pairs` between table_1 and table_2 partition to make use of `partition-wise` join